# How to enable disable dropdown based on user logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to disable my dropdown based on the user login.
I store the user type in session.

Now admin creates user. and then that user can login and edit his details.

I want to allow only some fields to be allowed to be edited by that user.

Like i don't want to allow him to edit his user_type.

Now if i remove them from my form field there comes an error on data truncated in mysql. and if i disable it through html it shows same error.

Please help me

the is controller code:

```
public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    $user_type = $this->session->userdata('user_type');


    if($user_type =="admin")
        {

            if ($id) 
                {
                    $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
                    count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';



                    // Set up the form
                    $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
                    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

                                // Process the form
                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
                    {

                        $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('emp_id','name','last_name','email','password','phone','gender','designation','user_type','blood_group','date_birth','status','address'));

                        if(!empty($data['password'])) 
                        {
                            $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);
                        } else {
                            // We don't save an empty password
                            unset($data['password']);
                        }
                        $key=$this->user_m->save($data, $id);

                        redirect('admin/user/index');
                    }

                }

                        // Load the view
                        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/users/edit';
                        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);

        }

    elseif($user_type=="employee")
        {   



            if ($id) 
            {
                $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_emp($id);

                count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';

                $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
                $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
                $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

                        // Process the form
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
                {

                    $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('emp_id','name','last_name','email','password','phone','gender','designation','user_type','blood_group','date_birth','status','address'));


                    //$data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);

                    if(!empty($data['password'])) 
                    {
                        $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);
                    } else {
                        // We don't save an empty password
                        unset($data['password']);
                    }

                    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');


                    $this->user_m->save($data, $id);


                    redirect('admin/user/index');
                }

            }

            // Load the view
            $this->data['subview'] = 'employee/profile/edit';
            $this->load->view('employee/_layout_main', $this->data);



        }

    else
    {
        echo "You Seem To Be Lost";
    }


}
```

The Edit View

```
        <h3><?php echo empty($user->id) ? '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Add a User' : 'Edit User ' . $user->name; ?></h3>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <table class="table">

            <tr>

    <td>Employoee ID</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('emp_id', set_value('emp_id', $user->emp_id)); ?></td>

</tr>



<tr>

    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $user->name)); ?></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('last_name', set_value('last_name', $user->last_name)); ?></td>

</tr>



<tr>

    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $user->email)); ?></td>

</tr>


<tr>

    <td>Password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>

</tr>



<tr>

    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('phone', set_value('phone', $user->phone)); ?></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>Gender</td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('gender', array('Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'), $this->input->post('gender') ? $this->input->post('gender') : $user->gender ); ?></td>    

</tr>


<tr>

    <td>Designation</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('designation', set_value('designation', $user->designation)); ?></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>User Type</td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('user_type', array('admin' => 'admin', 'employee' => 'employee','support_staff'=>'support_staff'), $this->input->post('user_type') ? $this->input->post('user_type') : $user->user_type ); ?></td> 

</tr>


<tr>

    <td>Blood Group</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('blood_group', set_value('blood_group', $user->blood_group)); ?></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>Date Of Birth</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('date_birth', set_value('date_birth', $user->date_birth)); ?></td>

</tr>

<tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('status', array('Active' => 'Active', 'Inactive' => 'inactive', 'Delete' => 'delete'), $this->input->post('status') ? $this->input->post('status') : $user->status ); ?></td>  
</tr>



<tr>

    <td>Address</td>
    <td><?php echo form_textarea('address', set_value('address', $user->date_birth)); ?></td>

</tr>



<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"','onClick="image()"'); ?></td>
</tr>




    </table>




  <script>
    $(function(){
   $('#spinnerInput').spinner();
  });
   </script>




    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: I suggest to indent/format code properly if you wish someone help you

Comment: @DonCallisto Yes i will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply check for logged in user type.

```
If (admin) {
  // SHOW DROP DOWN
}
else {
  // SHOW JUST TEXT (SELECTED ONE FROM DROP DOWN)
  // HIDE THE DROP DOWN BOX USING CSS PROPERTY: `display:none`
}
```

Comment: data truncated for user_type

Comment: This would mean that you are trying to insert data that would overflow the allocated storage for that column.

Comment: Please check in DB the width of column: user_type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99922/discussion-between-rajan-and-pupil).

Answer (score 1):

```
If ($user_type =="admin") {
  $select = '';
}
elseif($user_type=="employee"){
  $select = 'disabled';
}
// to prevent warning use this<?php isset($select) ? $select : ''; ?>
// Above is shortcode for if(isset($select)){echo $select;}else{echo '';}

<select <?php isset($select) ? $select : ''; ?> >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```